# Residual current in 5 V circuit

Tags: power-supply, led, zener

I am using a 3 V DC supply to light a 3 V LED.

I want to immediately stop the LED upon disconnecting power, but the LED stops after 2 seconds.

So how to stop the LED immediately? What size Zener diode do I have to use and do I need to connect it in series or parallel?

Comment: That's not how this works. A Zener diode is just a voltage reference (or limiter). Please show a schematic of your circuit.

Comment: So how to stop LED immediately?

Comment: Please show a schematic of your circuit.

Comment: `upon disconnecting power` you say. This means **to cut the physical connection** between the PSU (or at least one lead of it) and your LED.  But the behaviour you explained seems more like a `turn off` rather than `disconnection` of the PSU. To prevent this ambiguity put a schematic of your setup/circuit.

Comment: Please check check schematic in my question posted today

Comment: @IdrisAbbas [Edit] **this** question with a photo of what you've actually built, showing us wires connected to things. A drawing on paper like you added to the other question is not useful.

Answer (score 1):

You specify when disconnecting power to your 3 V DC supply. So this is disconnecting the mains going to a mains to 3 VDC power supply.

The power supply's primary side input capacitors give the supply a long hold-up time.

Try adding a load resistor across the 3 VDC output to drain this and shorten the hold-up time. If you can afford the power and resistor heat generated, it's the simplest solution.

To start with, you could try a 39R 1 W resistor. This will dissipate 275 mW in itself ongoingly.

Comment: Please check schematic in new question posted today